# CSS3 background-origin property does work in firefox?

Tags: background-image, css

I want use CSS3 property to make a complicated background image which with corner shadow and so on.Including background image,left border image,right border image.So,for the `<div class="outer"></div>`I write the CSS below:

```
    .outer
    {
        background:url("title_main.png");
        background-repeat:repeat-x;

        background-clip: content;
        background-origin:content;
        -moz-background-clip: content;
        -moz-background-origin: content;
        -webkit-background-clip: content;
        -webkit-background-origin：content;


        -webkit-border-image:url("title_border.png") 0 15 0 15 stretch;
        -moz-border-image: url("title_border.png") 0 15 0 15 stretch;
        border-image:url("fancy_title.png") 0 15 0 15 stretch;
        border-width:0 15px ;

        width:80px;
        height:32px;
    }
```

In chrome browser it work well like:[image]

But the firefox doesn't like this:[image]

Why would this happened?How can I fix this?Make the firefox effect like the chrome?

Answer (score 0):

The values of the `background-origin` property are `content-box`, `padding-box`, and `border-box`, according to [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-origin).  So what you want is:

```
.outer {
    -webkit-background-origin: content;
    -moz-background-origin: content; /* Firefox 3.6 and below */
    background-origin: content-box; /* Firefox 4 and above */
    /* etc. */
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry,my firefox version is 3.6.13,no matter content-box or content,it still doesn't work

Comment: You should still write it in a way that's going to work in standards-compliant browsers, though, so that once you get it to work, it will be more likely to keep working in the future.