# Why the CSS3 background-clip or background-origin doesn't work? What's wrong with my code?

Tags: css, background-image

I want use three images to make a background:[image] [image] [image]

As well I want use CSS3 background-clip or background-origin property,to use multiple images
here is my css code:

```
    .border
    {
        background:url("fancy_title_main.png"),url("fancy_title_left.png"),url("fancy_title_right.png");
        background-repeat:repeat-x,no-repeat,no-repeat;
        background-position:center,left,right;

        background-clip: content,border,border;
        background-origin:content,border,border;
        -moz-background-clip: content,border,border;
        -moz-background-origin: content,border,border;
        -webkit-background-clip: content,border,border;
        -webkit-background-origin：content,border,border;

        border-width:0 15px;
        border-style:solid;

        width:80px;
        height:32px;
    }
```

however,it doesn't work,on firefox 3.6.6:[image]

in the firebug:[image]

In my css ,I set the `-moz-background-clip: content,border,border;` but it show `-moz-background-clip:border, border, border;`Why?

How can I make the background like I wanted?What's wrong with my CSS code?

Thank you

Comment: From the code and the screenshot, it looks like you've got a 15px border on both sides, which is covering up where the background should be.  So it's sort of hard to see the results you're getting.  A URL would help.  (And note also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578425/css3-background-origin-property-does-work-in-firefox/4578956#4578956 , which is also important.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to be using content-box, border-box, and padding-box.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-clip

Answer (score 0):

You might want `border-color: transparent` (and see also my comment above).

Comment: The black area is the border-style:solid effect,then I cancel it ,it still doesn't work